# Build fails now and then with duration 00:00 in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, gitlab

Our builds fail occasionally but duration is 00:00. Failure email isn't sent from these fails but a message to Slack is sent and we can see failed build in builds list. These errors occure even if we haven't changed the code. So far this error hasnät occured when code has changed.

There is a following error in build log:

```
An exception occurred while polling the repository.
Error: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.ExternalConnectorException:
No references received in the response from https://our.on-premise.gitlab.com/ourrepo.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack.
Status: 500, Reason: Internal Server Error
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitConnector.ReadRefs(IVssRequestContext requestContext, HttpResponseMessage response) in d:\v2.0\P1\_work\7\s\Tfs\Service\Build2\Extensions\SourceProviders\Git\GitConnector.cs:line 296
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitConnector.GetBranches(IVssRequestContext requestContext, ExternalConnection connection, Int32 timeoutSeconds, Boolean useAnonymousAccess) in d:\v2.0\P1\_work\7\s\Tfs\Service\Build2\Extensions\SourceProviders\Git\GitConnector.cs:line 108
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitSourceProvider.GetMatchingBranchRefs(IVssRequestContext requestContext, BuildDefinition definition, IList`1 branchFilters) in d:\v2.0\P1\_work\7\s\Tfs\Service\Build2\Extensions\SourceProviders\Git\GitSourceProvider.cs:line 427
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitSourceProvider.GetSourceVersionsToBuild(IVssRequestContext requestContext, BuildDefinition definition, List`1 branchFilters, Boolean batchChanges, String previousVersionEvaluated, Dictionary`2& ciData, String& lastVersionEvaluated) in d:\v2.0\P1\_work\7\s\Tfs\Service\Build2\Extensions\SourceProviders\Git\GitSourceProvider.cs:line 358
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.BuildPollingJobExtension.Run(IVssRequestContext requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime queueTime, String& resultMessage) in d:\v2.0\P1\_work\7\s\Tfs\Service\Build2\Extensions\BuildPollingJobExtension.cs:line 98.
```

We have external Git (on-premises GitLab). Our administrators have said there isn't any errors in server's logs.

Where does this error come from? Is it network issue between Azure DevOps and our on-premise GitLab?

Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Here is a discussion about same problem: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d8e6644a-a1ef-45ee-8249-b6ebfe3c8aa2/tfs-2017-build-automatically-kicks-off-and-keeps-failing
But either there isn't any fix for this.